# For Each loop skips first item in array

Tags: excel, vba

I utilized Ron de Bruin's Outlook email generator with a few modifications for .To, .CC, .Subject, .Body fields. I as well included some coding to attach invoice files to the email as appropriate.

The first group in the attachments list is skipped.

```
Sub Create_Email()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim StrBody As String
    Dim Bundle As Variant, Group As Variant
        Bundle = Split(Worksheets("Extra").Range("G2").Value, ",")
        StrBody = Range("D5").Value & "<br>" & _
                  Range("D6").Value & "<br>" & _
                  Range("D7").Value & "<br>" & _
                  Range("D8").Value & "<br>" & _
                  Range("D9").Value & "<br><br><br><br>"
        mola = Range("B2").Value
        maybe = Format(mola, "mm")
        real = Format(mola, "mmmm yyyy")
        nope = Format(mola, "yyyy")
        InvPath = ("U:\BILLREC\M & R EG Billing\Invoices\" & nope & "\" & maybe & " " & real & "\" & "Electronic Invoices" & "\")

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = Range("C2").Value
        .CC = Range("D2").Value
        .Subject = Range("C5").Value
        .HTMLBody = StrBody
        For Each Group In Bundle
            pdfFile = "Group" & Group & ".pdf"
            .Attachments.Add InvPath & pdfFile
        Next Group
        For Each Group In Bundle
            xlsFile = "Group" & Group & ".xlsx"
            .Attachments.Add InvPath & xlsFile
        Next Group
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The "Bundle" array is sourced from a vlookup on the workbook itself based off of the group number, in a ####, ####, ##, #### format.

Ultimately, it works except when the files aren't named with our standard naming conventions, or it's the first group number in the list.

If there is a single "group" number, it does not attach the files at all. (I presume this issue is for the same reason - that it's the first item in the array.)

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the `On Error Resume Next` to see whether it is throwing an error? E.g. if you had a leading space in your cell's value (perhaps having `" 1234,3423,12,3131"` instead of `"1234,3423,12,3131"`) then your `.Add` could fail as the file `"Group 1234.pdf"` may not exist.

Comment: I had considered that possibility. The dataset containing the array is pulled from a Vlookup. I've manually changed multiple possible results that the vlookup would then return, and be pulled in by the macro. In each case, regardless of order or anything else, it simply does not attach the files for the first group listed in the array.

Comment: You could try adding a quick sanity check with [GetAttr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/getattr-function) just after InvPath is created - GetAttr just returns some file attributes or throws error 53 if the file doesn't exist. Try: `MsgBox InvPath & "Group" & Bundle(0) & ".pdf" & " : " & GetAttr(InvPath & "Group" & Bundle(0) & ".pdf")` If that doesn't throw an error then at least we can say the file exists

Comment: I'll give that a shot when I get back to the office in the morning. I'll also push out a data-set mock-up and attach here so it can be seen in "real time."  Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Ok, GetAttr did kick a run-time 53, however I confirmed that the file _does_ exist in the specified location.  I double-checked the data-sets for possible errant spaces at the front of the list, and there are none; however they were formatted as text, rather than number.  Would this potentially be the cause?

Comment: Further playing resulted in a runtime error 9. Subscript out of range.

Comment: I do not know _why_ it was skipping the first item in the "Bundle" collection, however in the source cell, I concatenated a '", "' into the source cell for the collection, and it worked as intended. Instead of the array being derived from `4263, 8826, 14, 326` it's now derived from `, 4263, 8826, 14, 326` and functioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to u/barrow, who's suggestion allowed me to see that it was genuinely missing Bundle(0) in the item count.

> You could try adding a quick sanity check with GetAttr just after
>   InvPath is created - GetAttr just returns some file attributes or
>   throws error 53 if the file doesn't exist. Try: MsgBox InvPath &
>   "Group" & Bundle(0) & ".pdf" & " : " & GetAttr(InvPath & "Group" &
>   Bundle(0) & ".pdf") If that doesn't throw an error then at least we
>   can say the file exists

My solution was to concatenate an additional delimiter into the source cell for the split.  Thus `Worksheets("Extra").Range("G2").Value` would return the results of `=CONCATENATE(","," ",VLOOKUP(Interface!A2,Data!A:D,4,FALSE))`rather than `VLOOKUP(Interface!A2,Data!A:D,4,FALSE).` It seems like voodoo, but it forced the split to identify that first delimiter in `Bundle = Split(Worksheets("Extra").Range("G2").Value, ",")` and thus identify the first item within the collection.

Thank you, everyone, for all your assistance!